# Changing backgroud color of Jquery UI Autocomplete Combobox per each result

Tags: jquery, combobox, autocomplete

Hi everyone We are using Jquery UI Autocomplete Combobox in our company and we have a scenario that for each item that comes from a webservice and is loaded into the Autocomplete Combobox, we should set the background color of the item relevant to its group Color. For example for an item with the group of "Fire Fighting", We should set the background Color of that item to Red, or Green for the group of "Parks".
We changed the background color with the below piece of code:

```
 (function ($) {
        $.widget("ui.combobox", {

            _create: function () {
                var input, a, that = this, select = this.element.hide(),
                                            selected = select.children(":selected"), value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "", wrapper = this.wrapper = $("<span>").addClass("ui-combobox").insertAfter(select);

                function removeIfInvalid(element) {
                    var value = $(element).val(), matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(value) + "$", "i"), valid = false;
                    select.children("option").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                            this.selected = valid = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    if (!valid) {
                        // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                        $(element).val("").attr("title", value + " ").tooltip("open");
                        select.val("");
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
                        }, 2500);
                        input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                input = this.input = $("<input>").appendTo(wrapper).val(value).attr("title", "").addClass("ui-state-default ui-combobox-input").autocomplete({ delay: 0, minLength: 0, source: function (request, response) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                    response(select.children("option").map(function () {
                        var text = $(this).text();
                        if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                            if (request.term != '') {
                                return { label: text.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>"), value: text, option: this };
                            }
                            else {
                                return { label: text.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "$1"), value: text, option: this };
                            }
                    }));
                },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        that._trigger("selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option

                        });
                    },
                    change: function (event, ui) {
                        if (!ui.item)
                            return removeIfInvalid(this);
                    }
                }).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-right");

                input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

                    // We Changed this part to get the functionality that we want 
                    // ------------------------------
                   var customStyle = $(item.option).attr("style");


                    return $("<li style='list-style-type: none;" + customStyle + "'>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
                };

                // ------------------------------ 

                a = this.a = $("<a>").attr("tabIndex", -1).attr("title", "").tooltip().appendTo(wrapper).button({
                    icons: { primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s" }, text: false
                }).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-left ui-combobox-toggle").click(function () {
                    // close if already visible
                    if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                        input.autocomplete("close");
                        removeIfInvalid(input);
                        return;
                    }

                    // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                    $(this).blur();
                    // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete("search", "");
                    input.focus();
                });

                input.tooltip({ position: { of: this.button }, tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight" });
            },

            destroy: function () {
                this.wrapper.remove();
                this.element.show();
                $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
            },
            disable: function () {
                this.input.prop('disabled', true);
                this.input.autocomplete("disable");
                this.a.button("disable");
            },
            enable: function () {
                this.input.prop('disabled', false);
                this.input.autocomplete("enable");
                this.a.button("enable");
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

We Fill the Value, Title, and Background Color as below:

```
  $.each(data['d'], function (i, option) {

                        $('#comboboxSubject').append($('<option/>').attr('value', option.SubjectID).attr('title', option.SubjectGroupID).css('background-color', option.BackGroundColor).text(option.SubjectName));


                    });
```

It works fine, but considering that this combobox is filterd by another combobox, we have to destroy the combobox and create it again, but after destroying, it shows the result with its default background color.
it seems that _Create function runs just one time, so it doesn't show our background colors anymore.
Any workaround?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Actually it's too complicated to reproduce. As we told we have changed the background color in the _Create function, but after destroying and creating the combobox using .combobox(), this function doesn't run, even breakpoints aren't hit. we are wondering that how and in what function it recreates itself.